# Python : Broke phone troubleshooting app

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a simple troubleshooting app for broken phones and solutions to the problems, about 5 minutes in and I can't get passed line 4 when the user enters the phone model, it just stops instead of continuing the dialogue. I have no clue why. Any help is much appreciated. Also on line 6, I'd love to make it so that when the user writes a line of text about whats wrong with the phone, it picks out words like "broke" "cracked" "wet" etc. but I have no clue how so again, any help is much appreciated!

```
brand = raw_input("Please state your phone brand. ")
if brand.lower() == ("iphone"):
    iphone = raw_input ("Please state the model. ")
    if iphone.lower() == ("2G"):
        iproblem2g = raw_input ("Please state your problem. ")
        if iproblem2g.lower() == ("broken") or ("broke"):
            ibroke = raw_input ("Is the hardware broken or the software? ")
            if ibroke.lower() == ("hardware") or ("hard"):
                print ("...")
```

Comment: You need to indent line 2.

Comment: @pp_ I think you mean line 3.  To my experience text editors don't start at 0. :)

Comment: Although this question has a relation with another question, it is not a duplicate, but a super-set.
This code has many problems that can be addressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few issues.  Try this:

```
brand = raw_input("Please state your phone brand. ")
if brand.lower() == ("iphone"):
    iphone = raw_input ("Please state the model. ")
    if iphone.lower() == ("2g"):
        iproblem2g = raw_input ("Please state your problem. ")
        if iproblem2g.lower() in ("broken", "broke"):
            ibroke = raw_input ("Is the hardware broken or the software? ")
            if ibroke.lower() in ("hardware", "hard"):
                print ("...")
```

Indentation is very important in Python.  Also, "2G" would have never have matched an input value since the input values are being lowercased.  Finally, matching multiple values is simpler in a list or tuple and wouldn't have worked the way it was (it would have always returned True).

Why always True?  Take for example `if iproblem2g.lower() == ("broken") or ("broke"):`.  This is checking `iproblem2g.lower() == ("broken")` OR `("broke")`.  `("broke")` will always be True since it is considered a [Truthy value in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) thus the entire conditional will always be True.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This line is probably semantically wrong (i.e., it compiles but does not work as you expect):

```
iproblem2g.lower() == ("broken") or ("broke")
```

You are actually asking if

```
(iproblem2g.lower() == ("broken")) or ("broke")
```

that means

```
(iproblem2g.lower() == ("broken")) or True
```

And this will always be True

You can´t check if something is "==" two things in this way. If you want to do this kind of question (is a == b or is a == c) you should use either:

```
 (iproblem2g.lower() == ("broken")) or  (iproblem2g.lower() ==  ("broke"))
```

or, more Pythonesc

```
iproblem2g.lower() in ["broken","broke"]
```

However, even this question is not a good choice, because it will only match the perfect word "broken" or "broke", and not texts that contain it. It will probably be much better to ask:

```
   "broken" in iproblem2g.lower() or "broke" in iproblem2g.lower()
```

In this way you will find the word in any sentence.

You can make it better by creating a simple function that checks if any of a set of words is in a sentence:

```
def check(words,sentence):
    for word in words:
        if word in sentence:
            return True
    return False
```

You can even do some pre-processing using .lower() and .trim()

Finally, there is a kind of small trick that you didn´t notice: if "broken" is the string, "broke" always will be (since it is a substring), so you do not need to check for both.

Comment: He didn't notice because he wasn't looking for it.  He was looking at case-insensitive equality.